# Simulate Mock Location on Android Device via DDMS

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a GPS navigation application for Android 2.3.3 which I have been working on. I am currently trying to simulate locations via a GPX file through DDMS. While this works perfectly find on the android emulator, I am unable to get it working on an actual device.

I am able to see the device on the under the "Devices" tab, but I am unable to send any mock location data, or GPX data as the options are under "Emulation Control" tab are grayed out.

I have noticed that previous questions on StackOverflow mention that it is not possible, however the Google docs titled "Using DDMS" - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html state the following (at the bottom of the page)

> Setting the location of the phone
>
> If your application depends on the location of the phone, you can have
>   DDMS send **your device** or AVD a mock location. This is useful if you
>   want to test different aspects of your application's location specific
>   features without physically moving. The following geolocation data
>   types are available to you:

I am just wondering  how to send fake location data to a device via DDMS.
Thank you for your help in advance, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: On my phone in the developers option there is a configuration to accept mock locations. I do not know if your phone has it but try to enable it if it is.

Comment: @Yury: Thank you for the prompt response. I have that configuration set up as well as the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission. From what I have heard/read up on it only allows you to use setTestProviderLocation(..) method to create mock locations from the application itself ( I could be wrong )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bilzac, your understanding is correct. Simply put, Android's documentation is misleading. Many developers have been confused by this. You cannot load a gpx file and send to device like you do on the emulator contrary to what the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Possible if you activate mock locations on your device. 
Than add ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission to your manifest.

You can write now your own MockLocationManager which generates mocj locations.

Easiest way is to you use an app which generates mock lactions for you. [GPS Route Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forgottenprojects.mocklocations&feature=also_installed) works quite fine. Possible to store kml files on the sdCard or defines own routes